# Send data form android to php server

Tags: java, php

I have my sql database server which contain a table named entry
I want to update that table
I am sending data from wifi or mobile network
I am designing that code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_nm);
    dob=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_dob);
    phone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_phone);
    email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_email);
    gender=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
    display=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_display);
    temp=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_temp);
    id_name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_id_name);
   db = openOrCreateDatabase( "hospital.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null); //localdb
    try {
        final String CREATE_TABLE_CONTAIN = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS detail ("
                + "id INTEGER primary key AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + "name TEXT,"
                + "dob DATE,"
                + "phone TEXT,"
                + "email TEXT,"
                + "gender TEXT,"
                + "temperature INTEGER);";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CONTAIN);


        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo wifiNetwork = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        NetworkInfo mobileNetwork = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if(wifiNetwork != null && wifiNetwork.isConnected() || mobileNetwork != null && mobileNetwork.isConnected()){
            Toast.makeText(SubmissionActivity.this,"Connection Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try{
                    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT name,dob,phone,email,gender,temperature FROM detail", null);
                    if(cur.getCount() > 0){
                        cur.moveToFirst();
                        postParameters1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name1",cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("name"))));
                        postParameters1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dob1", cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("dob"))));
                        postParameters1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone1", cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("phone"))));
                        postParameters1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email1", cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("email"))));
                        postParameters1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender1", cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("gender"))));
                        postParameters1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("temp1", cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("temperature"))));
                        resp =httpClient.executeHttpPost("http://117.211.123.25/vb/submit.php", postParameters1);

                        if (resp.contains("table created on server")){
                            Toast.makeText(SubmissionActivity.this, "Data are uploading on server... Please Wait!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            while(cur.isLast()!=true){
                            cur.moveToNext();
                            postParameters1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name1",cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("name"))));
                            postParameters1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dob1", cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("dob"))));
                            postParameters1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone1", cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("phone"))));
                            postParameters1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email1", cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("email"))));
                            postParameters1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender1", cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("gender"))));
                            postParameters1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("temp1", cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("temperature"))));
                            resp =httpClient.executeHttpPost("http://117.211.123.25/vb/display.php", postParameters1);
                            Toast.makeText(SubmissionActivity.this, "Data are uploading on server... Please Wait!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                             
                            }
                            db.delete("detail", null, null);
                        }
                    }
                }   
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(SubmissionActivity.this, "ERROR "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        }   
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(SubmissionActivity.this, "ERROR "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(View v) {
                              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                                    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name1", name.getText().toString()));
                                    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dob1", dob.getText().toString()));
                                    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone1", phone.getText().toString()));
                                    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email1", email.getText().toString()));
                                    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("temp1", temp.getText().toString()));
                                    String response = null;

                                    //tmp=Integer.parseInt(temp.getText().toString());

                                    int selectedId = gender.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                                    radioSexButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId); 

                                        switch (selectedId){    
                                        case R.id.radio0:
                                            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender1", radioSexButton.getText().toString()));
                                            break;
                                        case R.id.radio1:
                                            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender1", radioSexButton.getText().toString()));
                                            break;
                                        }
                                        boolean status=hasConnection();
                                        if(status==true){
                                            try{
                                                    localDbStorage();

                                                    response =httpClient.executeHttpPost("http://117.211.123.25/vb/submit.php", postParameters);
                                                    if (response.contains("table created on server")){
                                                    //Toast.makeText(SubmissionActivity.this,response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                    Toast.makeText(SubmissionActivity.this, "1 record added on server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                    if(tmp > 100)
                                                        Toast.makeText(SubmissionActivity.this, "Temperature is high", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                    }   
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        Toast.makeText(SubmissionActivity.this,"Server not available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                        localDbStorage();

                                                    }
                                            }catch(Exception e){
                                                Toast.makeText(SubmissionActivity.this,"error "+e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            Toast.makeText(SubmissionActivity.this,"Connection Fail",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            localDbStorage();
                                        }//localdb

                                        }
                       public boolean hasConnection() {
                           ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

                           NetworkInfo wifiNetwork = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
                           if (wifiNetwork != null && wifiNetwork.isConnected()) {
                            return true;
                           }

                           NetworkInfo mobileNetwork = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
                           if (mobileNetwork != null && mobileNetwork.isConnected()) {
                            return true;
                           }
                           NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                           if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
                             return true;
                           }
                           Toast.makeText(SubmissionActivity.this,"No network",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           return false;
                         }
                       public void localDbStorage(){                          
                           try{             //localdb
                            int selectedId = gender.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                            radioSexButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
                            name2=name.getText().toString();
                            dob2=dob.getText().toString();
                            phone2=phone.getText().toString();
                            email2=email.getText().toString();
                            temp2=temp.getText().toString();

                            switch (selectedId){    
                            case R.id.radio0:
                                gender2=radioSexButton.getText().toString();
                                break;
                            case R.id.radio1:
                                gender2=radioSexButton.getText().toString();
                                break;
                            }                                               
                            db.execSQL("INSERT or replace INTO detail (name, dob, phone, email, gender,temperature) VALUES('"+ name2 + "','" + dob2 + "','" + phone2 + "','" + email2 + "','" + gender2 + "'," + temp2 + ");" );
                            Toast.makeText(SubmissionActivity.this, "1 record added on localdb", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            if(tmp > 100)
                                Toast.makeText(SubmissionActivity.this, "Temperature is high", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(SubmissionActivity.this, "ERROR "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                        }

                       }
       });

        display.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_name1", id_name.getText().toString()));
            String response = null;
            try {
                response =httpClient.executeHttpPost("http://117.211.123.25/vb/display.php", postParameters);
                Toast.makeText(SubmissionActivity.this, "Detail is "+response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(SubmissionActivity.this, "ERROR "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

}

but that time i want to send data form more than one layout.xml file in one table,
please help me to connect my code to server.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think you should be creating a web service that will do the actual database work. This type of logic should not go into the actual client app. You then would submit data to the web service in a format such as JSON or XML that your web service would handle and store.

With this much domain specific logic in the client device, you would be rolling out updates constantly for bug fixes and features.

There are also several security concerns when giving an external connection this much control to your database.